# Azure SQL database unavaliable on management portal, but working

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I created a db on my server on azure, and it works well, and can be managed with sql server management studio, and the related website also works well, but on the management portal, the database is **unavaliable**. It appears on the list of databases under the server.
I deployed the database from my local server with ssms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Muller, are you still able to interact with your database via the Azure portal?

Comment: Can you try to see if you can access it from the classic portal? manage.windowsazure.com If it's still inaccessible from there, I would recommend filing a support request with Microsoft.